# Table Join condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
I have two tables 

Table A       : 
                 Item    Lookup
                  A        X
                  B       null
                  C        Y
                  D        K

Table B       :   
                   Lookup
                     X
                     Y
                     Z

I want to join these tables and get output like 

              Item    Lookup
               A       X
               B       null
               C       Y
```

I wanna pick up all matching lookup and as well as null lookups in my output view. can anyone tell me the join condition

Comment: what have you tried so far? from the data you have given us you don't need to join the tables as all the information is on Table A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want rows in `A` that either match `B` or have a `NULL` lookup.  You would do this with an `inner join` and a special condition:

```
select distinct a.item, a.lookup
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on (a.lookup = b.lookup) or (a.lookup is NULL);
```

If you have an index on `lookup`, then `exists` is better for performance:

```
select a.item, a.lookup
from tableA a
where a.lookup is null or
      exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.lookup = a.lookup);
```

EDIT:

Using a `left join` with a `where` condition is also possible:

```
select distinct a.item, a.lookup
from tableA a left join
     tableB b
     on a.lookup = b.lookup
where (a.lookup is NULL and b.lookup is NULL) or
      b.lookup is not null;
```

Comment: yes you are write if left join is done. it will also show value of `D`

Comment: Gordon, add a distinct in your select to get the exact output the OP requested, and maybe an order by a.item

Comment: @JeremyC.  . . . A `distinct` has no relevance to the query, and would only slow it down.  The OP doesn't really insist on the ordering, but it is clearly ok to have an `order by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff was just checking out the output of your query and compared it to the output OP had given so just thought I might mention it

Comment: Gordon I tried your code and the performance is going down by folds. Is there any other way without using or? Working on a table  with millions of records.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - your join has the unfortunate side effect of doing a cartesian join between table a rows where lookup is null and table b. Hence the need for the distinct to flatten the rows down. Probably also the reason for the OP's performance degradation.

Answer (score 3):

The following query will return all records of `TableA` that have `Lookup` in `TableB`, or have a `NULL` `Lookup`:

```
SELECT Item, Lookup
FROM TableA
WHERE (Lookup IS NULL) OR Lookup IN (SELECT Lookup FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Item, A.Lookup FROM A, B WHERE A.lookup=B.lookup OR A.lookup IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also do it via a left outer join:

```
with tablea as (select 'A' item, 'X' lookup from dual union all
                select 'B' item, null lookup from dual union all
                select 'C' item, 'Y' lookup from dual union all
                select 'D' item, 'K' lookup from dual),
     tableb as (select 'X' lookup from dual union all
                select 'Y' lookup from dual union all
                select 'Z' lookup from dual)
select a.item,
       a.lookup
from   tableA a 
       left outer join tableB b on (a.lookup = b.lookup)
where  a.lookup is null
or     a.lookup = b.lookup;

ITEM LOOKUP
---- ------
A    X     
C    Y     
B
```

Comment: I think this sql query should be more simple

Comment: feel free to add your own answer, if you think you can simplify things! *{:-)